# Wining prizes based off probabilities

Tags: javascript, node.js, probability-distribution

I was curious on how wheel spinning based of chances algorithm would work so I wrote this code

I created an object with each prize and its probability

```
const chances = {
        "Apple" : 22.45,
        "Peaches" : 32.8,
        "Grapes" : 20,
        "Bananas" : 6.58,
        "Strawberry" : 18.17
    }
```

then I generate a random number and check if its within the prize's winning ranges

```
const random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
var rangeStart= 0;

    for (var key in chances){
        var rangeEnd= rangeStart+ chances[key];
        if (rangeStart*100 < random &&  random <= rangeEnd*100){
            console.log(rangeStart*100+" < "+random+" <= "+rangeEnd*100);
            console.log("You won a "+key)
            break;
        }
        rangeStart+= chances[key];
    }
```

you can check the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5h9tygkd/1/)

am I in the right path?

Comment: Why `10000` ? Is that a magic number or is there some logic behind that choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, instead of `10000` stick to percentages `100`.
To prove that your code works fine (if you're unsure about the used algorithm), in order to test it **sample the results** of many iterations. If the collected results are close to the expected original values - that's a good sign you're on the right track:

Here's an example with 1,000,000 iterations. The precision seems pretty decent:

```js
const chances = {
  "Apple" : 22.45,
  "Peaches" : 32.8,
  "Grapes" : 20,
  "Bananas" : 6.58,
  "Strawberry" : 18.17
};

const results = {};

const generate = () => {
  
  const random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  var rangeStart = 0;

  for (var key in chances){
    var rangeEnd = rangeStart+ chances[key];
    if (rangeStart < random &&  random <= rangeEnd){
      results[key] ??= 0;
      results[key] += 1;
      break;
    }
    rangeStart+= chances[key];
  }
};

// noprotect
const samples = 1000000;
for (let i=0; i<samples; i++) generate();

Object.entries(results).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  console.log(`${k} ${(v / samples * 100).toFixed(2)}% (Expected: ${chances[k]}%)`); 
});
```